# How to use ImageWriter to produce data in SurfaceView

Tags: android, image, video-streaming

I want to preview my image using ImageWriter in android. I am using imagereader in and want to preview it in SurfaceView. How to use the imagewriter in android.

Answer (score 0):

If the application already has an `Image` from `ImageReader`, the application can directly queue this `Image` into `ImageWriter` (via `queueInputImage(Image)`), potentially with zero buffer copies.

Read [more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageWriter.html#queueInputImage(android.media.Image))

I also suggest using really popular handy libraries like `Picasso` or `Glide`if you're getting images from net, thought you're asking about `ImageWriter` . These libraries can load pictures from `url` directly into `imageview` in 3 lines.

Comment: So I have to provide the surface to imagewriter like this: imageWriter = ImageWriter.newInstance(mSurfacePreview,8);. Then queue the image as follow:imageWriter.queueInputImage(reader.acquireNextImage()); and deque the image to extract the image object for conversion as follow:Image image = imageWriter.dequeueInputImage(); Is my path correct or not?

Comment: Yes, you get it! Don't forget to close reader and writer after you're done using them

Comment: But, when I try to queue the image, it gets in it, but when I try to deque it, it throws error of NullPointerException. I am continuously capturing images. Still I need to close the Writer?

Comment: 02-27 12:19:56.557 13927-14062/com.nirajgandha E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3Process: com.nirajgandha, PID: 13927
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.media.Image android.media.ImageWriter.dequeueInputImage()' on a null object reference at com.nirajgandha.services.Camera2Service$3.run(Camera2Service.java:325) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)         Logcat of my app crashing

Comment: it states that your imageWriter instance is null for some reason although you get to queue images there..About closing, you only need to close it after you're done getting images and using them like in onDestroy of your activity or when you know that the work is finished. Maybe you're closing it and that's why the exception? You should debug and see after which line imageWriter instance gets null or else post your code as an edit to your question.

Comment: Now my instance is not null. But now it throws new error that Src and Dest image should be same. Though I am not changing anything in YUV_420_888 format.